# How can I get rid of bodies lying outside my front door?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

A few months ago as I fast traveled to Whiterun to deposit some items to my home, some mages, who were apparently cultists tried to attack me.

Needless to say, I put them down, and looted their bodies appropriately. Unfortunately, this has the result of their bodies still lying on the street. Every time I revisit Whiterun, their bodies lay stark naked on the pavement, while Ali'kir warriors say the same thing every time: "What's this?" and "What a damn shame."

I'd really like to get rid of this body.  Do bodies have some natural decay period?   If possible without the use of commands.  The bodies have been lying on the streets of Whiterun for nearly two months (of in-game time).

Comment: you can pick them up by holding the "use" key while you're next to them, then you could dump then in an inconspicuous location.

Comment: This will be a fun question on the "Hot Network Questions", also which system/console?